# Representation of Lie algebra to Lie group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a simple simply connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ and let $H$ be a simple subgroup of $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak h$. Suppose that I have a finite dimensional highest weight representation $V$ of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ and I restrict this representation to $\mathfrak h$. Now is the restricted representation is the differential of a representation of $H$ ?

Comment: You are conflating representations of Lie groups and Lie algebras: These are closely related but not the same. In particular, it makes no sense to say: "a representation of ${\mathfrak h}$ is a representation of $H$ as well."

Comment: I was a bit informal. I mean do we have a representation of $H$ whose differential is the restricted representation of $\mathfrak h$.

Comment: Good: Do you know any examples of representations of simple Lie algebras which do not come from the corresponding simple Lie groups?

Comment: Of course example exists for non-simply connected simple Lie groups lie $SO(2n+1)$.